# How to map a list of Urls to a JSON string

Tags: entity-framework

I have a POCO object that stores a list of Urls and I would like to store it in a string column in is serialized version. How can I achieve this with EF code first ?

```cs
class MyProfile {
    public int Id {get; set; }
    public IList<Url> Images {get; set}
}
```

I would like to be able to store it in a Table as :

```
1,["http1", "http2"]
2,["http3", "http4", "http5"]
etc.
```

Comment: it's the same with anything dealing with json. you build a native data structure (array, object, whatever) in your language of choice, and then you do your language's equivalent of `json_encode()` to do the conversion once, at the end.

Comment: @MarcB: So you mean there is no way to transform data in EF between my POCO and the database. Object that I pass are really wire/raw objects.